# "Group" a list by "keys"?

Tags: elisp

I want to map a "flat" structure like:

```
'(("Jimmy Carter" 10 1 1924)
  ("Donald Trump" 6 14 1946)
  ("George W. Bush" 7 6 1946)
  ("Bill Clinton" 8 19 1946)
  ("Barack Obama" 8 4 1961))
```

to:

```
'((1924
   (10
    (1
     ("Jimmy Carter"))))
  (1946
   (6
    (14
     ("Donald Trump")))
   (7
    (6
     ("George W. Bush")))
   (8
    (19
     ("Bill Clinton"))))
  (1961
   (8
    (4
     ("Barack Obama")))))
```

i. e. group a list by some "keys", in this example year, month and day of birth.  What is the best way to do that for the general case?  Is there another solution for a simple case where there is only one "key" per element (say, `'democrat` and `'republican`)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [`hash-tables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html):

```
(let ((ht (make-hash-table))
      (ret ())
  (dolist (record my-data)
    (push record (gethash (my-key record) ht ())))
  (maphash (lambda (key records)
             (push (list key (transform record)) ret))
           ht)
  ret)
```

here

- `my-data` is your original list
- `my-key` extracts the grouping key (e.g., year)
- `transform` maps the flat list `(name a b c)` to the hierarchy you want to see in the return value.